# ParametricPlot3D: Combine plot that depends on 2 variables with plot that depends on 1 variable

Tags: plotting

I'm using `ParametricPlot3D` to plot 2 surfaces that are parameterized by 2 variables. Now I would like to add a curve that is parameterized by just one of these variables. I want the curve to appear in the same plot as these 2 surfaces. Can `ParametricPlot3D` do this? All domains are the same.

Comment: tried [Show](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html)?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: `Show` works now. Thank you!